# Existence of an element in a ring with a given property

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a ring (commutative, with unity), $\mathfrak p\subset R$ a prime ideal, $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module such that $S_1^{-1}M=0$, where $S_1=R\setminus \mathfrak p $. How does one show that there is an $r∈R$ such that the set of all prime ideals in $R$ not containing the ideal $(r)$ has $\mathfrak p$ as one of its elements and possesses the property that for any other $\mathfrak q$ from this set, $S_2^{-1}M=0$, where $S_2=R\setminus \mathfrak q$?

Comment: Do you mean "show that there is an $r$ such that $r\notin \mathfrak p$"? Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Does $r$ need to satisfy any condition? If not, you can take $r=1$

Comment: **Hint.** From $M_P=0$ you get an element $r\in R\setminus P$ such that $rM=0$.

Comment: @user26857: thanks! Your hints are very helpful. The question is no longer topical.